# Regex - Return only non repeated items

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to return only non-repeating elements from a string.

This is my current regex:

```
/{{([1-9]|[1-9][0-9])}}/gm
```

Here are some samples of what I need:

```
{{1}}{{2}}{{3}}{{4}}{{5}}{{1}} => {{1}}{{2}}{{3}}{{4}}{{5}}
{{1}}{{2}}{{3}}{{4}}{{2}}{{1}} => {{1}}{{2}}{{3}}{{4}}
{{1}}{{2}}{{2}}{{4}}{{1}}{{1}} => {{1}}{{2}}{{4}}
```

I have tried the following lookaround:

```
/{{([1-9]|[1-9][0-9])}}(?!.*\1)/gm
```

Kind of works for this example, but it get the last element instead of the first:

```
{{1}}{{2}}{{3}}{{4}}{{5}}{{1}} => {{2}}{{3}}{{4}}{{5}}{{1}}
```

With this example it don't work:

```
Olá, {{1}}

Só pra lembrar, sua consulta foi agendada para o dia {{2}} às {{3}}h.

Por favor, não se atrase

Se por acaso tiver algum imprevisto e não puder comparecer, nos avisem com {{4}}h de antecedência.

{{1}}, te esperamos aqui!
```

The string above returns all elements:

```
{{1}}{{2}}{{3}}{{4}}{{1}}
```

Comment: Why don't you match all `{{x}}` occurrences and then use the host programming language to filter the captured groups for duplicates?

Comment: @knittl When working with high concurrency things, it's preferable to process things just once rather than twice.

Comment: Use `[\s\S]` or `[^]` instead of `.` to make it `({{(?:[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])}})(?![\s\S]*\1)` or even better`({{(?:[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])}})(?![^]*\1)`

Comment: @CaioKawasaki Please add lang-tag or tool you're using. Also helpful to describe the aim/task. If this is for replacement and your lang provides callbacks as a regex-replacement, you could use some check-array for only replacing first matches.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand problem correctly, here is what you need:

1. You want to match `{{<num>}}` patterns
2. But don't want to match duplicates occurrence of same pattern
3. Duplicates of `{{<num>}}` can occur any where in multiline text
4. You prefer to match first occurrence of duplicates

Since you showed Javascript syntax of your regex, I am also using lookbehind feature in my regex as per modern Javascript behavior:

```bash
({{(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\d)}})(?<!^(?:[^]*\1){2})
```

- [RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/Yeuo1J/1)
- [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/Yeuo1J/2)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `({{(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\d)}})`: Match `{{<num>}}` text and capture in group #1
- `(?<!^(?:[^]*\1){2})`: Negative lookbehind with a dynamic length to assert failure if we have 2 repeats of capture group #1